# How to Use the Text Copy Feature of Sushi for Ubuntu 22.04 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

In Ubuntu 22.04's Gnome Sushi, I can copy text while previewing.

In Ubuntu 20.04's Gnome Sushi, I cannot copy text while previewing.

I would like to use Ubuntu 20.04, but I want to use copy text while previewing.

Is it possible to install the Gnome Sushi for Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu20.04 environment?